# Rewrite these codes using only one loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Please help me reduce the code quantity.

This is my code and it's working without any problems.

flag : boolean,

likeArr: ["A", "B", "C"],

dislikeArr: ["D", "E", "F"]

```
likeOrDislike( flag, likeArr, dislikeArr ) {

    const username = this.props.user.username // This username is dynamic.
    if (flag) {
        for (let i=0; i<likeArr.length; i++) {
            if (likeArr[i] === username) {
                return console.log('you already LIKED this post.')
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (let i=0; i<dislikeArr.length; i++) {
            if (dislikeArr[i] === username) {
                return console.log('you already DISLIKED this post.')
            }
        }
    }

    if (flag) {
        for (let i=0; i<dislikeArr.length; i++) {
            if (dislikeArr[i] === username) {
                dislikeArr.splice(i, 1)
                likeArr.push(username)
                break
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (let i=0; i<likeArr.length; i++) {
            if (likeArr[i] === username) {
                likeArr.splice(i, 1)
                dislikeArr.push(username)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am using 4 similar loops and I want to use only one or two loops preferably.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey and welcome. A general tip: your question would probably get a lot better reception if it didn't sound like it was a college assignment that you are just dumping on stackoverflow for a free solution without any effort shown on your end whatsoever (whether that's actually the case or not).

Comment: Hey, what do you mean? I only want the answer. I don't care the other else. Do you have the exact answer? I also tried using one loop, but the values of the props are automatically changing.

Answer (score 1):

Added an else condition to splice item if the item exists and push the item if it doesn't.

```js
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
        const username = this.props.user.username  //This username is dynamic
        if(flag){
            if(likeArr.includes(username)){
                console.log('you already LIKED this post.');
            }

            if(dislikeArr.includes(username)){
                dislikeArr.splice(dislikeArr.findIndex(x => x === username), 1);
            }
            likeArr.push(username);
        }
        else{
            if(dislikeArr.includes(username)){
                console.log('you already DISLIKED this post.')
            }

            if(likeArr.includes(username)){
                likeArr.splice(likeArr.findIndex(x => x === username), 1);
            }
            dislikeArr.push(username);
        }        
    } else {
        console.log('login to like or dislike')
    }
```

Comment: push is working, but splice is not working, I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion . Ill look into it again.

Comment: Previously, the function would push the item in the array even though it spliced it. Now, it will not push the item after taking it out.

Comment: This function is called in onClick handler. I have 2 buttons that trigger this function. In every case, the console log appears.

Comment: Which console log comes up? "login to like or dislike" OR one of the if condition ones? Also, i updated the function. Could you try again and post the console.log?

Comment: when i click "Like", "you already liked this post" log appears and the likeArr is spliced. If this log appears, the array should not be sliced, nothing should actully happen.

Comment: Updated the function again. Verify.

Comment: Still not working. when I click, one continuously pushes and the other does nothing (this should post console.log).

Comment: what are you sending as parameters? 

flag, likeArr, dislikeArr, blogPoster . console log all of them and post them here please.

Comment: flag: boolean, likeArr =  [ "ABC", "DEF", "GHI" ], dislikeArr = [ "JKL", "MNO", "PQR" ] and ignore blogPoster. And let's say this.props.username is "ABC" or "JKL".

Comment: Thanks, i get the issue . I've updated the function to the best of my understanding.

Comment: It works from the second click. But, at first click, it gives console.log and the array is pushed. Only one thing should happen.